# two people drawing on same canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, socket.io, real-time

I am making a real-time paint app in html5 canvas. When a single user draws on the canvas then everything goes fine , but when two users draw at same time , everything gets messed up , for example if one changes color , the color for all client changes , and lines start drawing from one point to other . How can this be fixed ? Thanks , here is my code.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width="600";
canvas.height="500";
var radius = 10;
var mouse = {x:0,y:0};
var drag = false;
var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 20, 20);
 };
  imageObj.src = 'rhino4.png';
$scope.colorChange = function(color){
  Socket.emit("colorChange",color);
};
Socket.on("colorChange",function (color) {
  context.strokeStyle = color;
  context.fillStyle = color;
})
$scope.radiusChange = function(size) {
  Socket.emit("radiusChange",size);
}
Socket.on("radiusChange",function (size) {
  radius = size;
  context.lineWidth = radius*2;
})
context.lineWidth = radius*2;
var putPoint = function (mouse) {
  if(drag){
    context.lineTo(mouse.x,mouse.y)
    context.stroke();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(mouse.x,mouse.y,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
    context.fill();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(mouse.x,mouse.y);
    context.globalCompositeOperation='source-atop';
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 20, 20);
    context.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
  }
}
Socket.on("putPoint",function (mouse) {
  putPoint(mouse);
});
var engage = function(mouse){
  console.log("in engage",mouse);
  drag = true;
  putPoint(mouse);
}
var disengage = function(){
  drag = false;
  context.beginPath();
}
var socketPutPoint = function(e){
  mouse.x = e.offsetX;
  mouse.y = e.offsetY;
  Socket.emit("putPoint",mouse);
}
Socket.on("engage",function (mouse) {
  console.log("engaging");
  engage(mouse);
});
var socketEngage = function (e) {
  mouse.x = e.offsetX;
  mouse.y = e.offsetY;
  console.log(mouse);
  Socket.emit("engage",mouse);
}
var socketDisengage = function (e) {
  mouse.x = e.offsetX;
  mouse.y = e.offsetY;
  console.log(mouse);
  Socket.emit("disengage",mouse);
}
Socket.on("disengage",function (mouse) {
  disengage();
})
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',socketDisengage);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave',socketDisengage);
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',socketEngage);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',socketPutPoint);
```

I thought of changing the color back to original in colorChange method after putpoint , but that does not seem to work

Comment: You will need to keep track of each client's "last point" and prior to issuing `context.lineTo(mouse.x,mouse.y)` do a `moveTo` to the client's "last point" (that will also apply to the color so you can set the correct client's color).

Comment: understood about the color , but i am little unclear about point, will i have to do move to old points after each draw or after the other client has fired mouseup event

Comment: Try to on your mousedown handler (`socketEngage`) to do (plus the original code there) `mouse.last_x = e.offsetX; mouse.last_y = e.offsetY;` (beginning of the function), in your mousemove handler (`socketPutPoint`) `mouse.last_x = mouse.x; mouse.last_y = mouse.y;` (beginning of the function), and on `putPoint` before `context.lineTo(mouse.x,mouse.y)` add `if (mouse.last_x && mouse.last_y) context.moveTo(mouse.last_x,mouse.last_y);` to get an idea of what I am talking about =) Hope that you could do the rest of adjustments.

Comment: thanks for the hints :) i fxed the color one , and the line one is almost fixed , please write an answer so that i can accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some whiteboarding hints:**

*All the following code is pseudo-code!*

- Use websockets for communication. Several popular websocket libraries are  [SocketIO](http://socket.io/) and [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr). Websocket libraries often have fallback methods when websockets are not supported.
- Use JSON to serialize your drawing data. The nice thing about JSON is that it automatically takes JavaScript objects / arrays and makes a string from them that's suitable for websocket transmission. And visa-versa: automatically receives JSON strings and rehydrates the strings into JavaScript objects / arrays.

  ```
  var command = {
      client:'sam', 
      points:[{x:5,y:10},...],
      // optionally add styling (strokeStyle, linewidth, etc)
  };

  // serialize a command 
  var jsonCommand = JSON.stringify(command);

  // deserialize a command
  var command = JSON.parse(jsonCommand);
  ```
- Its very important (critical!) to keep all drawings "atomic" -- each path drawing should be complete including styling. **Don't** start a `context.beginPath` and emit a series of `context.lineTo`'s over time!

  ```
  draw(command.points);

  // ALWAYS issue complete drawing commands
  // including styling (if any)
  function draw(points);
      var ptsLength=points.length;
      context.beginPath;
      context.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
      for(var i=0;i<ptsLength;i++){
          var pt=points[i];
          context.lineTo(pt.x,pt.y);
      }
      context.stroke();
  }
  ```
- Don't leave a path open: So don't design a socket app to send partial drawing points (which leaves the drawing operation incomplete). This implies you should wait for a users drag operation to complete before emitting a full drawing operation.

  ```
  var isDown=false;
  var commands=[];
  var points;
  var lastX,lastY;


  // on mousedown ...
  // reinitialize the accumulated points array
  // with the mousedown point
  function handleMouseDown(e){

      // tell the browser we're handling this event
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      // get mouse position
      lastX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      lastY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // reset the accumulated points array
      // add the point to the accumulated points array
      points=[ {x:lastX, y:lastY} ];          

      // set the isDown flag
      isDown=true;
  }


  // on mousemove ...
  // add the current mouse position to the accumulated points array
  function handleMouseMove(e){

      if(!isDown){return;}

      // tell the browser we're handling this event
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      // get mouse position
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // draw the newest local path segment
      // so the local user can see while they're drawing
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(lastX,lastY);
      context.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
      context.stroke();
      // save the last x,y
      lastX=mouseX;
      lastY=mouseY;

      // add the point to the accumulated points array
      points=[ {x:mouseX, y:mouseY} ];
  }


  // on mouseup ...
  // end the current draw operation
  // and add the points array to the commands array
  function handleMouseOut(e){

      // tell the browser we're handling this event
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      // clear the isDown flag
      isDown=false;

      // add the current set of points 
      // to the accumulated commands array
      commands.push({
          client:myName,
          stroke:myCurrentStrokeColor,
          points:points
      });

  }
  ```
- Use a separate loop to emit our local drawing commands to the server and to draw incoming remote drawing commands:

  ```
  // vars to schedule drawing from remote clients
  // and sending local drawings to server
  var nextDrawingTime, nextSendingTime;
  var drawingTimeDelay=1000; // or some other delay, but don't be a burden!
  var sendingTimeDelay=1000; // or some other delay, but don't be a burden!

  // start the processing loop (it runs continuously non-stop)
  requestAnimationFrame(process);

  function process(time){

      // a simplification ...
      // don't interrupt if the local user is drawing
      if(isDown){ return; }

      // draw incoming strokes
      if(time>nextDrawingTime && receivedCommands.length>0){

          // set the next drawing time for remote draws
          nextDrawingTime=time+drawingTimeDelay;

          // draw all accumulated received commands
          for(var i=0;i<receivedCommands.length;i++){
              var c=receivedCommands[i];
              if(c.client!==myName){
                  draw(c.points);
              }
          }
          receivedCommands.length=0;

      // emit outgoing strokes
      } else if(time>nextSendingTime && commands.length>0){

          // set the next emitting time for locally drawing paths
          nextSendingTime=time+sendingTimeDelay;

          // JSON.stringify
          var jsonPacket=JSON.stringify(commands);

          // reset the set of local drawing commands
          commands=[];

          // emit to server for broadcast to everyone

      }

      requestAnimationFrame(process);
  }
  ```
- Have the server do some important tasks:

  - Add a timestamp to each broadcast if your choice of websockets library doesn't automatically include a timestamp.
  - Save all received drawing commands (database) because things go wrong and you will probably have to full re-synchronize the clients from time to time.
- Mousemove fires about 30 times per second so a large quantity of points will be accumulated. To reduce data transmission size, consider using a path reduction algorithm to remove redundant points. One good algorithm is the [Douglas Peucker path simplification algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm).

There's so much more to a good whiteboard app, but that's all the time I have for now ... Good luck with your project! :-)

Comment: This is the best explanation i have read about white-boarding . Thanks a lot!! :) .

Answer (score 1):

You will need to keep track of each client's "last point" and prior to issuing `context.lineTo(mouse.x,mouse.y)` do a `moveTo` to the client's "last point" (that will also apply to the color so you can set the correct client's color).

To get an ideia you can try to do:

- on your mousedown handler (`socketEngage`) to do (plus the original code there)

  mouse.last_x = e.offsetX;
  mouse.last_y = e.offsetY;

(beginning of the function)

- in your mousemove handler (`socketPutPoint`)

  mouse.last_x = mouse.x;
  mouse.last_y = mouse.y;

(beginning of the function)

- and on `putPoint` before `context.lineTo(mouse.x,mouse.y)` add

  if (mouse.last_x && mouse.last_y)
      context.moveTo(mouse.last_x,mouse.last_y);

Hope that you could do the rest of adjustments.

Comment: When whiteboarding its **very important to keep all drawings "atomic"** -- each path drawing should be complete including styling: `.beginPath`, `.moveTo`, `.lineTo`, `.strokeStyle='something'`, `stroke`. **Don't leave a path open:** So don't design a socket app to `engage` & `disengage` (which leaves the drawing operation incomplete). This implies you should **wait for a users drag operation to complete** before emitting a full drawing operation.

Comment: hi @markE , if I understood you right then , I should not emit events while the user is dragging the mouse , then how shall i show what the user has painted to all other users in realtime ? Can you please explain a bit , maybe with an answer , Thanks :)